# How to differentiate between interval and numeric columns in dplyr::across()?

Tags: r, class, dplyr, lubridate, across

I have a tibble containing Intervals, created with lubridate.

```
library(tidyverse)
Interval=lubridate::interval(POSIXct(1)+1,POSIXct(1))
numeric=3
character="A"
tbl<-tibble(Interval,numeric,character)
```

with the title reflecting the class of the data in each column.
I want to apply a function to the *numeric* column only. Unfortunately, `Interval` is of type `double`:
'''
typeof(Interval)
[1] "double"
'''
So that `mutate(tbl,across(is.double,mean))` renders

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  Interval numeric character
     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    
1       -1       3 A
```

I do get the desired result with: `mutate(tbl,across(is.numeric&!is.interval,mean))`

```
 Interval                                numeric character
 <Interval>                                <dbl> <chr>    
1 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC--1970-01-01 UTC       3 A
```

But this seems quite tiresome.
Is there a more direct way to just select for *numeric*, excluding *Interval*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`rlang::is_bare_double()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/bare-type-predicates.html).

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

mutate(tbl, across(where(is_bare_double), mean))

# A tibble: 1 × 3
  Interval                                numeric character
  <Interval>                                <dbl> <chr>    
1 1970-01-01 00:00:01 UTC--1970-01-01 UTC       3 A
```

Also note the predicate should be wrapped in `where()`; it will still work unwrapped, but yields a warning since this is deprecated.